# How to get user input decimal format

Tags: python-3.x, format, decimal

Hi I am having trouble getting a numeric user input and formatting the variable to decimal like so.

```
usrIn = Decimal input('How much money do you have in your account? ')
print (usrIn)
```

or

```
usrIn = input('How much money do you have in your account? ')
usrIn = Decimal('{0:0.5f}'.format(usrIn))
print (usrIn)
```

or

```
usrIn = input('How much money do you have in your account? ')
print (usrIn)
accBalNZD = Decimal('{0:0.5f}'.format(usrIn))
```

Also I cant simply assign a variable an amount and format it for some reason it works with other stuff.

```
prevAmtNZD = Decimal('{0:0.5f}'.format(0.0000000))
print (prevAmtNZD )
```

But this does work having trouble implementing please help.

```
exRandUSD = Decimal('{0:0.5f}'.format(random.random()* (0.780 - 0.720) + 0.720))
```

Comment: Where are your `()`s for decimal in the first one? `value = Decimal(input('...'))`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to import Decimal. Do this by typing:

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

Then, you can simply use:

```
UserIn = Decimal(input("........................."))
```

Decimal is just another type of variable, so you use it in the same way as int(input()) or str(input())

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: fyi: You definitely wouldn't need to cast the return value of input() to a string, it is already a string (in Python 3).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to list the types of issues you have seen with each approach you tried.

```
from decimal import Decimal
usrIn = Decimal(input('How much money do you have in your account? '))
print(usrIn)
```

Keep in mind that the input method (in Python 3) returns a string (try printing it out with repr). That is why your second/third code snippets fail. If you cast that string to a float it would work:

```
from decimal import Decimal
usrIn = input('How much money do you have in your account? ')
print(repr(usrIn))
usrIn = Decimal('{0:0.5f}'.format(float(usrIn)))
print (usrIn)
```

Comment: Thank you both sometimes its the simple things you miss